# How to test Wi-Fi connection's stability?

Tags: wireless-networking

How can I test the stability of a wireless connection for an specific time period, or test the stability of the connection in a rather longer time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution is probably to just start a ping and check for packet loss.

- Start the command prompt by pressing `Win + R` and typing `cmd` + OK
- Start a ping by entering the command `ping -t 8.8.8.8`

  - (This will ping Googles DNS server until you press `Ctrl + C` to cancel it)
- If you loose connection to the internet, you will get error messages.

To really make sure that it is the Wi-Fi adapter that is failing, it would be better to ping your default gateway. (Probably 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know you could use '-t' when using ping command.

Answer (score 0):

> Answer to the original question

The answer is really simple. Try another computer, laptop etc. If you want to check whether the usb adapter works fine, plug it in another device.

Now for the internal adapter try rolling back on a previous version. It doesn't necessarily mean that it is not compatible with windows 10, it might mean that the drivers crash. Try different versions and check if any of them work.

Had this issue in the past on a brand new laptop, and when I rolled back the drivers, everything worked fine.

**Edit:** Have you considered whether this is a Router's issue and not your adapters'? Do other devices get disconnected as well?

**Update:** There are lots of things that can cause this issue.

- If the problem is with your PC only, check your Firewall Settings, there might be something that's blocking your access. Try windows troubleshooting. You will be surprised how many times this helps, even though some consider it does nothing.
- If the problem is with your WiFi try a different channel in the router's WiFi settings.

Do you get the same issues when you use an ethernet cable? If yes then there is something wrong with your router. It might even be your ISP's issue. There are tons of things that can be wrong.

Comment: I have tried uninstalling, rolling back and reinstalling drivers. I also tried installing windows 8's drivers in compatibility mode in windows 10. I have tried almost hundreds of different advice/tricks/solution I could find on the internet. I have given up on the internal adapter.

Comment: The USB adapter works fine on my computer but the problem as I mentioned it the possible connection drops which I don't know when could happen and therefor I don't know how to test.

Comment: @Log check my edit question

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really appreciate your time. 
You are answering and referring to the initial problem with the adapter/connection but as I mentioned in the title and the question before and after the edit I just want to test the stability of the connection in the current situation as I have given up on "fixing" it because I'm considering a clean OS Install and if it does not work switching to Linux Mint.
And again thanks for your answer and your time.

Comment: @Loga, since you accepted an answer, I tried to give you a general view on what is the root of the issue. You don't need to clean install your pc for that. After your exam (good luck btw) try spending a few hours checking. As I said it could be your router, and you might spend time formatting and reinstalling for something that isn't caused by your computer or OS.

Comment: @Loga, try using an ethernet cable. If this persists, check another device. If it keeps happening, then it is definitely your router

Comment: Thanks. I would absolutely try them.
Too bad my vote for your answer does not "count". This community needs more users like you. Cheers.
And again, thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

The following batch file will do a quick test and reset for you:

```
@echo off
Rem Microsoft Windows 10 ping test to gateway.
Rem Run batch file from an administrative command prompt.

cls
:starting
Rem Send one ping to the gateway.  Write the results to a file.
ping 192.168.1.1 -n 1 > pingtest.txt

Rem Search for unreachable in the file. 
c:\windows\system32\findstr.exe "unreachable" pingtest.txt

Rem errorlevel 0 reset the adapter if 1 then wait 10 minutes and test again
if %errorlevel%==1 goto waiting

Rem unreachable was found reset the adapter.

Rem write the date and time the reset was done.
echo Reset date: %date% time: %time% >> resettimes.txt

Rem issue netsh interface show interface to find your adapter's name to reset
Rem my adapter is "wi-fi"

netsh interface set interface "wi-fi" disable
timeout /t  5
netsh interface set interface "wi-fi" enable
:waiting
echo "It is online waiting 10 minutes"
timeout /t  600
goto starting
```